# Sending nested array object to mvc controller gives null

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following :

array structure in javascript for **selectedValues**

> at [0] index an contains array [0][1]
>
> at [1] index an contains array
> [0][1]

and so on....

```
function OnSave()
{
var id =getvalue()
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
content:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
dataType:"JSON"
url:"....",
data: JSON.stringify({
id:id,
model:selectedvalues,
}),
success : function (data){
......
}
}
```

ViewModel in c#

```
public class ViewModel{
int id,
List<QuestionAnswer> QAs,

}

public QuestionAnswer
{
int Id;
string ans;

}
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Save( int id,List<ViewModel> model)
```

I am able to get id in controller method but model parameter contains always nulls values for the fields..So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: user 
data: [{
id:id,
model:selectedvalues
}],

Comment: how you are creating `selectedvalues` variable?

Comment: Var selectedvalues= []

Answer (score 0):

Ajax

```
 var QAsObj= {
                ans:"answerVal",
                Id:1

            };


var SendObject = {
           id:1,
        QAs: QAsObj,   //QAsObj same name as in Modal

            }
 $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Controllername/Save',
                contentType: 'application/json',  // send data type to server
                dataType: 'json',  //return type of data from server
                data:JSON.stringify(SendObject),
                //  asyn: false,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                    // do stuff here

                },
                error: function (response, status, xhr) {

                    alert(response.statusText);

                }
            })
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Save( SaveViewModel model)
```

View Model

```
    public class SaveViewModel{
int id,
List<QuestionAnswer> QAs,

}

public QuestionAnswer
{
int Id;
string ans;

}
```

I hope this will work fine , still you are facing error , comment below